# error on ec2 volume mount

Tags: amazon-ec2, mount, disk-volume

Am getting the following error while trying to mount a ec2 volume

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-XX-XX-XX-XX ~]$ sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt
mount: /dev/xvdf is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: unknown filesystem type '(null)'
```

Also, tried to mount the part as below

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-XX-XX-XX ~]$ sudo mount /dev/xvdf2 /mnt
    mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: What is your question, and what did you do already to try and resolve it, that didn't work? Also see: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My question is how to resolve the issue that I had. I had shared this because I could not find the answer anywhere else. Btw isnt my question obvious from the errors?

Answer (score 11):

Posting the solution that worked for me as I did not find this else where.....

First checked the dmesg to see the actual error

```
dmesg | tail
```

and found the error with duplicate UUID

```
[180875.598481] XFS (xvdf2): Filesystem has duplicate UUID 379de64d-ea11-4f5b-ae6a-0aa50ff7b24d - can't mount
[180970.058345] XFS (xvdf2): Filesystem has duplicate UUID 379de64d-ea11-4f5b-ae6a-0aa50ff7b24d - can't mount
```

so to fix this use the nouuid option

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-XX-XX-XX ~]$ sudo mount -o nouuid /dev/xvdf2 /mnt
```