# Cannot mount an existing EBS with xfs file system on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, unix, mount

I try mounting an existing EBS Storage (which has data) to an instance, but it keeps throwing this error.

```
mount: /dev/xvdf1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: unknown filesystem type '(null)'
```

These are the storage details:

```
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvda: 10.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: pmbr_boot

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
2      2097kB  10.7GB  10.7GB  xfs


Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvdf: 10.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: pmbr_boot

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
2      2097kB  10.7GB  10.7GB  xfs
```

How can I mount the partition?

Comment: mount: unknown filesystem type '(null)'

I would start to analyze the disk...

Comment: Take a look at https://serverfault.com/a/779439/153161